# Python super class reflection

Tags: python, reflection

If I have Python code

```
class A():
    pass
class B():
    pass
class C(A, B):
    pass
```

and I have class `C`, is there a way to iterate through it's super classed (`A` and `B`)? Something like pseudocode:

```
>>> magicGetSuperClasses(C)
(<type 'A'>, <type 'B'>)
```

One solution seems to be [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-inspect.html) and `getclasstree` function.

```
def magicGetSuperClasses(cls):
    return [o[0] for o in inspect.getclasstree([cls]) if type(o[0]) == type]
```

but is this a "Pythonian" way to achieve the goal?

Comment: The correct adjective is "Pythonic".

Comment: See also [Checking if A is a superclass of B in Python](/q/1938755/1157100).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`C.__bases__` is an array of the super classes, so you could implement your hypothetical function like so:

```
def magicGetSuperClasses(cls):
  return cls.__bases__
```

But I imagine it would be easier to just reference `cls.__bases__` directly in most cases.

Answer (score 11):

@John: Your snippet doesn't work -- you are returning the *class* of the base classes (which are also known as metaclasses). You really just want `cls.__bases__`:

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
class C(A, B): pass

c = C() # Instance

assert C.__bases__ == (A, B) # Works
assert c.__class__.__bases__ == (A, B) # Works

def magicGetSuperClasses(clz):
  return tuple([base.__class__ for base in clz.__bases__])

assert magicGetSuperClasses(C) == (A, B) # Fails
```

Also, if you're using Python 2.4+ you can use [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead of creating a list (via []), then turning it into a tuple (via `tuple`). For example:

```
def get_base_metaclasses(cls):
    """Returns the metaclass of all the base classes of cls."""
    return tuple(base.__class__ for base in clz.__bases__)
```

That's a somewhat confusing example, but genexps are generally easy and cool. :)

Comment: This post seems to no longer be relevant (John corrected his answer). If I were you, I'd delete this post.

Answer (score 4):

The inspect module was a good start, use the [getmro](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) function:

> Return a tuple of class cls’s base classes, including cls, in method resolution order. No class appears more than once in this tuple. ...

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> class B: pass
>>> class C(A, B): pass
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(C)[1:]
(<class __main__.A at 0x8c59f2c>, <class __main__.B at 0x8c59f5c>)
```

The first element of the returned tuple is `C`, you can just disregard it.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to know to order in which super() would call the classes you can use `C.__mro__` and don't need `inspect` therefore.

Comment: This didn't work for me. In my example, I got `class C(B): pass`, and `C.__mro__` results in `AttributeError: class C has no attribute '__mro__'`, whereas `inspect.getmro(C)` returns `(__main__.C, __main__.B)`. I'm using Python 2.7.6.