# Python grab class in class definition

Tags: python, reflection

I don't even know how to explain this, so here is the code I'm trying.

```
from couchdb.schema import Document, TextField

class Base(Document):
    type = TextField(default=self.__name__) 
    #self doesn't work, how do I get a reference to Base?

class User(Base):
    pass

#User.type be defined as TextField(default="Test2")
```

The reason I'm even trying this is I'm working on creating a base class for an orm I'm using. I want to avoid defining the table name for every model I have. Also knowing what the limits of python is will help me avoid wasting time trying impossible things.

Comment: I tried to find a way to do exactly what you are trying to do a while ago, with IronPython.  So far, I don't think it is exactly possible.  User.type should be a type, not a TextField object.

Comment: @jcao219, why should User.type be a type? `type` is not reserved in this case. (`type` is a function, not a bound method) To grab the class of an object in python you use the `__class__` attribute.

Comment: didn't quite understand what you wanted to do actually.
I thought you wanted to have a class inherit from an object, instead of a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class object does not (yet) exist while the class body is executing, so there is no way for code in the class body to get a reference to it (just as, more generally, there is no way for any code to get a reference to any object that does not exist).  `Test2.__name__`, however, already does what you're specifically looking for, so I don't think you need any workaround (such as metaclasses or class decorators) for your specific use case.

**Edit**: for the edited question, where you don't just need the name as a string, a class decorator is the simplest way to work around the problem (in Python 2.6 or later):

```
def maketype(cls):
    cls.type = TextField(default=cls.__name__)
    return cls
```

and put `@maketype` in front of each class you want to decorate that way.  In Python 2.5 or earlier, you need instead to say `maketype(Base)` *after* each relevant `class` statement.

If you want this functionality to get inherited, then you have to define a custom metaclass that performs the same functionality in its `__init__` or `__new__` methods. Personally, I would recommend against defining custom metaclasses unless they're really indispensable -- instead, I'd stick with the simpler decorator approach.

Comment: Metaclasses... interesting possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the other question [python super class relection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807/python-super-class-reflection)

In your case, Test2.__base__ will return the base class Test. If it doesn't work, you may use the new style: class Test(object)